# Help showing $y \cdot f(x+1) \leq \frac{C_0(p) \cdot y \cdot f(y)}{2} + \frac{x \cdot f(x)}{2}$

Tags: functions, polynomials, proof-explanation, game-theory

I was reading through [this paper](https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/%7Egchristo//Giorgos%20Christodoulou_files/ck05a.pdf) and noticed a seemingly simple algebraic lemma (Lemma 2 on page 6) for which a proof is not given. I cannot seem to prove the fact myself, so I was hoping to turn to the math commmunity for help.

The lemma is as follows: Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ of degree $p$ with non-negative coefficients. Then, for any $x,y \geq 0$,
\begin{align*}
y \cdot f(x+1) \leq \frac{C_0(p) \cdot y \cdot f(y)}{2} + \frac{x \cdot f(x)}{2}
\end{align*}
where $C_0(p) = p^{p(1 - o(1))}$.

I don't really understand what this $C_0(p)$ function represents and would appreciate any help in proving this lemma!

Comment: A side note: Lemma 3 in the paper, i.e.$$y(x+1)\leqslant \frac{\sqrt5-1}4x^2+\frac{\sqrt5+5}4y^2,\quad\forall x,y\geqslant0$$is false, e.g. if $x=y=t$ and $t→0+$. I wonder why a paper with crucial lemmas unpoven/unsourced could have been accepted at all.

Comment: @Saad Incidentally it is also a very famous paper in that field with ~530 citations to date.

Comment: After some manipulations, I suspect that this lemma (lemma 2 in the paper) only holds for $x,y\in\mathbb N$, which indeed is sufficient for derivations after it. Under this assumption, the optimal $C(p)$ for sufficiently large $p$ is given by$$C(p)=\max_{x>0}(2(x+1)^p-x^{p+1}).$$(Here the range $x>0$ is correct since the optimal $x$ is near $p$.)

Comment: @Saad I see, so this only holds for sufficiently large $p$? This would make sense considering the current answer and simple counterexamples (i.e. $\alpha = 2, \beta = 2, f(x) = x$). How did you go about deriving $C(p)$ here? If you put this into an answer, happy to accept it

Comment: @learning_linalg : This holds for $p=1$. For example, take $f(x)=x+1,x=1$ and $y=5$. I've added some observations in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the lemma is false.

For $f(x)=x^p,x=0$ and $y=C_0(p)^{-1/p}$, one has
$$y \cdot f(x+1)=C_0(p)^{-1/p}\color{red}{\gt}\frac{C_0(p)^{-1/p}}{2}=  \frac{C_0(p) \cdot y \cdot f(y)}{2} + \frac{x \cdot f(x)}{2}.$$

---

There are many counterexamples.

If $f(x)=Ax^p+B,x=0$ and $y\gt 0$ with $A\gt 0$ and $B\geqslant 0$, then
$$y \cdot f(x+1) \color{red}{\gt} \frac{C_0(p) \cdot y \cdot f(y)}{2} + \frac{x \cdot f(x)}{2}$$
is equivalent to
$$y\lt \bigg(\frac{2A+2B-BC_0(p)}{AC_0(p)}\bigg)^{1/p}.\tag1$$

Here, $2A+2B-BC_0(p)$ has to be positive, and then, every positive real number $y$ satisfying $(1)$ works as a counterexample.

So, one can say that the following is a counterexample :

- $f(x)=Ax^p+B,x=0$ and $y$ is a positive real number satisfying $y\lt \bigg(\dfrac{2A+2B-BC_0(p)}{AC_0(p)}\bigg)^{1/p}$ where $A,B$ are are real numbers satisfying $A\gt 0,B\geqslant 0$ and $A\gt \dfrac{(C_0(p)-2)B}{2}$.

---

**Added** : I'm going to add some observations.

$$y \cdot f(x+1) \le \frac{C_0(p) \cdot y \cdot f(y)}{2} + \frac{x \cdot f(x)}{2}\tag2$$

- $f(x)=x+1,x=1,y=4$ is a counterexample. So, it is false that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $p$ with non-negative coefficients, then for any pair of non-negative integers $(x,y)$, $(2)$ holds.
- $(2)$ holds for $f(x)=x+1, x=3/2,y=11/2$ where $p=1$. So, it is false that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $p$ with non-negative coefficients and $(2)$ holds, then $x,y$ are non-negative integers.
- $(2)$ holds for $f(x)=x+1, x=1,y=5$ where $p=1$.